# After infinispan 10.1.8 update: class file for org.infinispan.factories.scopes.Scopes not found

Tags: infinispan

I just tried to update my application to Infinspan 10.1.8.Final.  I am using Infinispan as a level-2 hibernate (5.4.18.Final) cache via this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
    compile group: 'org.infinispan', name: 'infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53', version: '10.1.8.Final'
```

The application compiles and starts, but the following is logged when I run the test suite:

```
warning: unknown enum constant Scopes.GLOBAL
  reason: class file for org.infinispan.factories.scopes.Scopes not found
warning: unknown enum constant DataType.TRAIT
  reason: class file for org.infinispan.jmx.annotations.DataType not found
```

Why is this happening?  Do I need to include another dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `compileOnly 'org.infinispan:infinispan-component-annotations:10.1.8.Final'` to the dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.

Both enums aren't required at runtime. They are using in compile time to generate metadata required by Infinispan.

Comment: This fixes my problem.  I don't understand why it wasn't included transitively from infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53. Maybe there is something wrong with my Gradle setup.

Comment: I don't know Gradle to reply to that. 
We have an example with maven [1] and I don't see any warning when compiling neither running it. [1] https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/hibernate-cache/local/pom.xml#L4

Comment: This seems to be caused by the fact that Infinispan defines the Maven scope of these dependencies in the BOM, rather than were they're actually used. Gradle doesn't like that (and I think for a good reason). I created [ISPN-12461](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-12461) in the Infinispan issue tracker.